# iphone always returns UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, orientation

I need to make sure that when my `UIViewController` loads, it rotates as needed.

I have implemented the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` methods and its all working fine, except when the app first loads (when the iphone is in landscape mode) or when going from a UIViewController which was is portrait mode the `interfaceOrientation` and the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` always returns portrait mode!

I have been reading blogs and even some SO questions, but none of them seem to address the underlying issue.

I am using a standard UINavigationController application. So the first view is the first pushed controller onto the stack. I have also tried asking the self.navigationController its orientation, with no luck either.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Here is my code for the viewWillAppear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    [self setPortraitMode];
else
    [self setLandscapeMode];
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is how I am printing out the current

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
NSLog(@"currentDevice: %d", (int)orientation);
NSLog(@"statusbar: %d", (int)[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
NSLog(@"nav controller: %d", (int)self.navigationController.interfaceOrientation);
NSLog(@"interface orientation: %d", (int)self.interfaceOrientation);
```

They all print out "1"

but when I put this code in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, then they print out the correct int values (1,2,3 or 4).

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question?

Comment: cant really remember, but by looking at the responses, I dont think so :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] for checking orientation use statusbar orientation to get the exact orientation :- [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation .  I also had problem while checking currentDevice orientation , it does not always return the exact orientation

Comment: have you returned yes in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: do you have any parent controller to this view controller which does not return yes for shouldAutorotate. also check this

Comment: one thing to remember that I mentioned, is that the actual orientation changes works fine. Its just when I start up the app the orientation is wrong and I cant fix it.

Comment: hey perhaps the problem is that you have handled the code of setPotraitMode or landscape mode in view will appear. Now viewWillAppear gets called before shouldAutorate method gets called.So initially the default orientation will be potrait when viewWillAppear gets called. Try handling your code in shouldAutoRotate or didRotate . This may fix your problem. Got my point? And also do check orientation with statusbar orientation only not with currentDevice orientation

Comment: good thought, but unfortunately no luck there, would it matter if I have the statusbar hidden?

Comment: I used this with UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) in viewWillAppear. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

What about checking the orientation in viewDidAppear: instead? You can use the 'animated' to decide if you will rotate with animation or not. You view may appear and then rotate, but I think that would an acceptable experience.

EDIT: as a follow up to my comments, here's the screen shot from Xcode 4 for UIInterfaceOrientation:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure--did you add your allowed rotations to your plist?

Comment: hmm, nope didnt try that, whats the key for that?

Comment: ah, did you mean `UIInterfaceOrientation` which if i read the docos correctly is for the initial startup, which is not what Im after here, I simply want to detect and adjust

Comment: Yes--I mean 'UIInterfaceOrientation'. My understanding is that it's about which orientations your app supports, not the initial startup. (see my post edit)

Comment: actually--I mean to say 'UIInterfaceOrientation' is about both startup and supported orientations.

Comment: i simply cannot get this to work, can you get a sample project running that this works against?

Comment: Maybe try adding a breakpoint to `-[UIViewController shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:]` and see if it is returning `NO` anywhere. If one of your view controllers returns `NO` all rotation is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone apps are always launched in portrait orientation, because the home screen is portrait-only.  Likewise, the launch image is intended to be displayed in portrait orientation.  The only exception is if the app is landscape-only.

(iPad apps can be launched in any screen orientation, and and you must provide separate launch images for both orientations.)

Comment: so you are saying that its not possible to rotate the view after the app loads, without manually moving the phone back to portrait and back to landscape again?

Comment: No, I'm saying that your app always starts up in portrait mode.  That's why the device orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait in viewWillAppear.  Test the behavior with the Notes app if you're unsure.

Comment: nope, in notes if I open it in landscape mode it starts as portrait but flips over into landscape mode

Comment: You wanted to know why device orientation is always UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait in viewWillAppear, and now you know.  If you have another questions you should ask it.

Comment: no, the first line in the question reads `I need to make sure that when my UIViewController loads, it rotates as needed.` I still dont have an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the rotations and orientations of the iOS App. I found that `self.interfaceOrientation` will always give you a correct result if called in `viewDidAppear` or after that.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` should be preferred when adding a view directly to `UIWindow`.

Hope it helps.