# UIDatePicker in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker, popover

I'm struggling with UIDatePicker. I thought I could add it to my current view just as I would an ordinary subview, but it didn't appear. After some searching, I found documentation for putting it in a popover. I followed those instructions and got it to work on the iPad. But popovers don't work on the iPhone. What do I need to do to make it work there? Why can't I simply add it like a regular subview?

Here's my iPad code:

```
-(void)selectADate: (CGPoint)p
{
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController
    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
    datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setTag:10];
    datePicker.date = self.displayedDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    UIPopoverController * popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    //popoverController.delegate=self;
    self.datePopover = popoverController;
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
    CGRect popoverLocation = CGRectMake(p.x-160, p.y-200, 320, 216);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverLocation inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame//
}

- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.displayedDate = [sender date];
    [self showMonthContainingDate:[sender date]];
}
```

My screen is currently laid out as a sort of calendar page showing a month of days. Each day's sell is a subview. At the top of the screen is a header, which has information on the year, month, etc. When the user taps the header, the date picker appears, and the calendar page displays the month selected that corresponds to the date chosen in the picker with the day highlighted (that day's subview's background has a different color).

I'm not sure why I even need a popover, unless it is just to provide a blank view on which to place the date picker that is in front of the tiled views of my calendar page. But then shouldn't I be able to simply add it as a subview and then call bringSubviewToFront:? I tried that, but it didn't work on the iPad, hence my use of the popover.

I can get it to display if I add it when I add the other subviews, but I want it to display when I tap the heading. Here's my tap code:

```
- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
   //tap gesture recognizer
   //Assume the user tapped on a day cell.
   for (UIView *dayCell in self.view.subviews) {
      if (CGRectContainsPoint(dayCell.frame, [sender locationInView:self.view])) {
         //found the cell that was touched.
     //NSLog(@"Found a view containing the touch with coords. %@",NSStringFromCGRect(dayCell.frame));
         for (UIView *insideView in dayCell.subviews) {
            for (UILabel *dayElement in insideView.subviews) {
               //found a subview of the day cell.
               if ([dayElement isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                  NSLog(@"Found a subview %@",dayElement.text);
               }
            }
         }
      }
      if ([dayCell isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
         // This is the heading label.
         UILabel * headingLabel = (UILabel *) dayCell;
         if (CGRectContainsPoint(headingLabel.frame, [sender locationInView:self.view])) {
            NSLog(@"The heading was tapped");
            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
               //iPhone code goes here
               [self iphoneSelectADate:[sender locationInView:self.view]];
            } else  {
               [self selectADate:[sender locationInView:self.view]];
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the currently nonworking iPhone code:

```
-(void)iphoneSelectADate: (CGPoint)p
{
   UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216, 320, 216)];
   [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];  //This is the default
   [datePicker setHidden:NO];
   [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}
```

If I step through in the debugger, I see this code is executed, but the datepicker does not display.

Comment: You absolutely can add it to your view like any other subview. If you tried that in code, you should show it, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore. However, I will say this. My screen is completely tiled with subviews. I was able to add it as a subview to the heading subview, but that subview is not big enough. So I thought of adding it to the heading's parent, which is just self.view. Nothing appears. I suspected that it might be there but be behind the other subviews. Perhaps I'll try again and post the code if it doesn't work.

Comment: @rdelmar, If I change the line [self.view addSubview:datePicker]; to [self.view.superview addSubview:datePicker]; it works. Any explanation why this would work but the code shown in my question does not? And what's the standard way to dismiss a date picker?

Comment: I don't know what you structure is. Try logging self.view and self.view.superview and see what they give you. It sounds like you have an extra view in there. To dismiss, I would just use [datePicker removeFromSuperview];

Comment: @rdelmar, Thanks. Got the dismiss going. Can you tell me how to do that logging? I need to learn how to display/list the view hierarchy somehow.

Comment: Just NSLog(@"%@",self.view) and NSLog(@"%@",self.view.superview)

Comment: @rdelmar, I'm not sure what to make of the results: self.view: <UIView: 0x8a8f040; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8a8e6c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a8f0f0>>
self.view.superview: <UIWindow: 0x8a8b060; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8a8bf00>>

Comment: Well, that's what you would expect for a normal setup -- your controller's view is a subview of the window. The thing that doesn't make sense, is why adding the picker with [self.view addSubview:pickerView] doesn't work. There doesn't seem to be any extra view there. Where do you have the iphoneSelectADate: method? How is it being called?

Comment: @rdelmar It is in the tap gesture recognizer. That recognizer is linked to self.view and triggers that event when I tap on the area of self.view occupied by the heading, which is a subview of self.view. I've put the code over on github (see below) if you want to look. I confirm the datepicker is getting put in the uiwindow when I add it to the superview because it doesn't rotate when everything else rotates when I select the hardware rotate simulation.

Comment: I was referring to this post of mine, below. Partly to show the whole project, and partly to learn github, I pushed it out to github.com/victorengel/calendar

Comment: @rdelmar, Since the problem is only when I trigger the code with my gesture recognizer, the thought occurred to me that I may have the gesture recognizer hooked up wrong. Maybe I have it hooked up to the controller instead of the view in the controller. If so, is there an easy way to fix this in the storyboard?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that would make a difference. But, I'm looking at your code, and you have this line: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { [self.view addSubview:datePicker]; }); The date picker is showing up as it should -- I thought you said you had to use self.view.superview addSubview....

Comment: I think you are looking in a method that is not used. I've since deleted that method but not pushed it to github yet.

Comment: @rdelmar, I just redid the tap gestures in the storyboard. I also deleted that unused method, did some cleanup, and repushed the code back to github.

Comment: @rdelmar, I think I figured out the problem and added my own answer for it. If you can explain why that works, feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the key to my problem. After reading through [this document](http://kevin.dew.name/post/18579273258/where-to-progmatically-lay-out-views-in-ios-5-and) on the various places to place orientation-related code, I decided on `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. I read through the document again and decided to try putting that code in `viewWillAppear` instead, and that seems to have resolved the problem.

The change to using `viewWillAppear` also required implementation of `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

It looks like `viewWIllLayoutSubviews` is needed for iPad but not iPhone, so I've also added this:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      //iPhone code goes here (empty, since calling showMonthContainingDate: doesn't work from here in iPhone
   } else  {
      //ipad code goes here
      NSDate *dayToDisplay = self.displayedDate;
      [self showMonthContainingDate:dayToDisplay];
      //iPad uses wrong dimensions unless the routine is called from here.
   }
}
```

One final note. There is one scenario where the orientation of the device is not set correctly -- that is landscape on an iPhone at launch. According to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864949/iphone-always-returns-uiinterfaceorientationportrait/5876532#5876532) the iPhone always launches in portrait unless it is a landscape-only app.

Comment: After you add the picker, viewWillLayoutSubviews is called again. The problem with putting what you did in viewWillLayoutSubviews, is that you're chaining together many methods, and one of those, takedown, removes all of self.views subviews, including the picker.

Comment: ViewWillLayoutSubviews is called again _because_ the picker was added. Apparently a change in views triggers the method. I had forgotten it was doing that and was going to deal with it later. Maybe the second one can be suppressed somehow.

Comment: Didn't changing to using viewWillAppearAnimated: work? It seemed to work when I tried it (at least to get the picker view to appear). I think that is a better place to put the code.

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm doing. That last comment was more about my learning than about making the app work. I'm not actually going to build the app that way. Sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: @rdelmar, Actually, there is still a problem. The rotation does not work properly from viewWillAppear:Animated: for some reason. It's calculating the wrong dimensions. I also don't think your idea about takedown is right, because I added code to not take down the datepicker, and it still didn't appear.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to add willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: which is needed if going the viewWillAppear:Animated: route.

Comment: hmm....I did a lot of logging, and putting logs in at the top, and then in the for loop in the takedown method, I saw the picker disappear during that for loop.

Comment: @rdelmar, did you see the actual picker being taken down, or did you see logs noting that it had been done? I can set breakpoints and po the object, but I don't see it on the simulator screen. In any case, I've updated my github with the solution that works for me.

Comment: I have one remaining issue, which I think I will not pursue because of the history I see there has been with trouble in this area on iOS. If I launch the iPhone simulator in landscape, it identifies as Portrait. The problem fixes itself if the device is rotated and rotated back. It's the initial launch orientation in landscape (on iPhone only) that is the problem. Project settings are default (allow all except upside-down portrait).

Answer (score 1):

`UIDatePicker` inherits from `UIView`, so you can add it just like a `UILabel`.  Make sure you give it a frame.

Something like this would work for the bottom of an iPhone screen:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216, 320, 216)];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];  //This is the default
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

It sounds like you likely have a subview layering issue, not a `UIDatePicker` issue though.

If that doesn't work, post some of your code and we'll help figure it out.

Comment: I think I'm making some progress. If I place the code in the method that displays the calendar page, the datepicker is displayed. If I place it in my tap gesture recognizer, it is not displayed. I don't want it to be displayed until the user taps the heading.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Partly to show the whole project, and partly to learn github, I pushed it out to https://github.com/victorengel/calendar (I've never used github before, so please let me know if I need to provide a different URL).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but UI changes for views that are already present require to be dispatched using the main_queue
for e.g.
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                   {
                       [self.view addSubview:yourSubview];
                   });`

Comment: Thanks. I'm not doing any threading, so I think everything is in the main queue. However, I'm new at this, and the only threading I've done is animation blocks (but not in this project).

Comment: ... or are gestures handled on a different thread? If so, that may be my issue.